# Call to a member function get_items() on a non object in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am making a plugin that works in collaboration with woocommerce WordPress plugin. I am getting an error when trying to get items for an order:

> "Fatal error: Call to a member function get_items() on a non-object in /home/telesqua/public_html/mehtab/wp-content/plugins/order-grabber/order-grabber.php on line 283"

and this is what is on line 283 and around it:

```
function post_order() 
{
if(isset($order_id))
{   
$order = new WC_Order($order_id);
}
$items = $order->get_items();
$number_of_items_in_this_order = $order->get_item_count();
```

Can anyone help me point out the problem?  I can provide the source file if needed.

Comment: Probably $order_id isn't set, so the object $order isn't created (class WC_Order() not instantiated).

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying jan Relilink. you are exactly right and i have the exact same idea about this, what i am trying to ask is that is there a reason why the class is not being instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

this is because it an add_action has to be executed after using the above code

```
add_action('init', 'post_order');
```